# Using SqlAlchemy models in a long running process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm coming from a PHP & Doctrine ORM background.

In doctrine orm, if I do a long running process like batch processing, it needs me to `clear()` the entity manager after processing some entities, to prevent 'ran out of memory'

[doctrine batch processing](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html)

If I'm going to do something like below in python and SqlAlchemy :

```
db = SqlAlchemy()
# .... 
# configure db instance and other stuff
# .....

def my_callback_func(param):
  my_model = MyModel(
    attr1 : '...',
    attr2 : '...',
  )
  db.session.add(my_model)
  db.session.commit()
    
#here i'm attaching above function as a callback
#filter is a object that monitors something, and it call the callback function #when requirements are satisfied.

my_filter.watch(my_callback)

#so my script will keep running
input()
```

Above code runs fine for now, for days actually.

Does SqlAlchemy tracks `MyModel` objects after saving them to database?

Is it possible that SqlAlchemy could collect(in memory) all the objects it saved, and "run out of memory" at some point?

BTW I'm aware of how to run a long process using Supervisor or something like that. Keeping it running is not the problem.

Comment: You might be interested in ["Is the Session a cache?"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache), and the Session basics in general. The identity map does store references to model objects, to some extent.